# Postresql matrix multiplication of a table (multiply a table by itself)

Tags: postgresql, matrix-multiplication

I have a square table similar to this:

```
  | c | d |
  | - | - |
a | 1 | 2 |
b | 3 | 4 |
```

I want to calculate matrix multiplication result where this table is multiplied by itself, i.e., this:

```
  | c  | d |
  | -- | - |
a | 7  | 10 |
b | 15 | 22 |
```

While I understand that SQL should not be my language of choice for this task, I need to do this in that language. How do I do this?

Comment: You'd have to define your own data type and operators for this.

Comment: "square table" is nonsense in SQL - table can have unlimited number of rows but limited number of columns. If the numbers of rows and columns are same, you would have to add another column to specify ordering of rows. Still the data representation would be very fragile. The matrix multiplication would be possible but SQL is not suitable for such tasks. Is it some school homework? Please prepare db fiddle with sample table and its columns.

Answer (score 1):

It will make your life easier if you represent your matrix elements as  `(i,j,a[i,j])`.

```sql
WITH matrix AS (SELECT * FROM
  (VALUES ('a','a',1), ('a','b',1), ('b','a',2), ('b','b',3)) AS t(i,j,a))
SELECT m1.i as i, m2.j as j, sum(m1.a * m2.a) FROM matrix m1, matrix m2
GROUP BY  m1.i, m2.j
ORDER BY i,j
```

This will handle sparse matrices nicely as well

Here a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DC0bO6wU) that you might be able to visualize.